# How to reject uploaded PDF file that contains executable attachments in PHP?

Tags: php, windows, validation, pdf

So far I've been able to detect a valid PDF by analyzing the structure of the file. 
I'm trying to detect anything executable that the pdf file might have attached/hidden. 
Is there anylibrary that I can use to extract attached files and analyze them?

*I used ClamAV to detect any malicious content and it works well but it needs the approval of architects in my organisation which takes time or might not happen at all :-( , so I need a good solution until then.

*The php script runs on Apache (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you use linux try to list the file inside archive and check if there are executable files.
This might be helpful https://superuser.com/questions/216617/zip-linux-view-files-in-archive

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use antivirus for all uploaded content is good thing, there is even ClamAV php extension. Next step would be to verify that pdf is really pdf - you can check beginning of the file if it starts with

> %PDF-

When talking about content which could be inside pdf, antivirus should be able to detect any hidden boogies there, but it's also up to pdf viewer to be secure if possible not Adobe Reader.